# Link users using geolocation and user profiles

Tags: android, html, ios, geolocation, user-profile

I am trying to work on a mental health app, one feature of which is to connect users to each other. I am kind of new to coding apps, so I am pretty much beating my head up against a wall right now. What I am trying to do is have users press a button, and with that, show a profile of a user near them. I have user profiles enabled in the app, but I can't figure out how to enable to "press button, see profile aspect."

I am currently using html5.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It would help if you showed us your code.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know why you have taged ios, but when i was bulding a simular application in ios i had a lot of help from this parse tutorial:

https://parse.com/tutorials/anywall

Learn how to use CurrentLocation and save it to every user, and then compare the users current location to the other users locations.

Maybe that might help you a little bit.